# shell_exec not running xvfb-run in php5-fpm but this is working well under apache2 ( mod_php )

Tags: shell-exec

shell_exec is not working for the command

xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 /var/sjs/slimerjs /var/www/html/sjs/www.js

But this same command working well in Apache2 ( mod_php )

So why php5-fpm can't run this command?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your php.ini that php-fpm used. Find `disable_functions` directive and delete `shell_exec` from value.
2. May be user (who runnig php-fpm), haven't permission to read/execute some files. Check permission with `ls -l /var/sjs/slimerjs /var/www/html/sjs/www.js` command. I think, that user must have permission for execute /var/sjs/slimerjs, and reading /var/www/html/sjs/www.js. You can add permission by command `chmod +x /var/sjs/slimerjs` and `chmod +r /var/www/html/sjs/www.js`, but that's not good for security, cause any user can exec/read files. Better add user to some group, change owner group for this files, and set permission 754 for first file, and 744 for second.